# Typo3 8.5 - Enable client-side caching

Tags: html, caching, typo3, browser-cache, client-side

I'm trying to enable client-side caching on my website powered by Typo3 8.5.3.

I have found this page :
https://typo3.org/documentation/article/using-cache-control-headers-in-typo3/

But i can't manage to make it work.

These are my settings, am I missing something?

```
config {
   no_cache = 0
   sendCacheHeaders = 1
   cache_period = 86400
   cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
}
```

I've included this on a template use in my website but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it's a matter of server configuration or only Typo3 configuration.

I want to enable client-side caching to meet google's recommendations on his "speed test" : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Here is a current header I get on a js file :

```
Date    Mon, 25 Sep 2017 14:01:18 GMT
Server    Apache
Last-Modified     Mon, 17 Jul 2017 07:13:51 GMT
ETag         "224cf4-20976e-5547e24169863"
Accept-Ranges       bytes
Content-Length      2135918
Content-Security-Policy     default-src * ; style-src * 'u…'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-WebKit-CSP       default-src *; style-src * 'un…'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
Content-Type      text/javascript
Strict-Transport-Security       max-age=31536000
X-XSS-Protection       1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options      nosniff
```

Comment: AFAIK google does recommend adding cache config for several mimetypes e.g. for images. That would be configured in the server's settings. Can you add the output of your pagespeed test somehow so we can have a closer look?

Comment: Here is a screen of my pagespeed test : http://hpics.li/8a05a14
It's mainly images, but there is also lot of css and js

Comment: Those cache settings arent controlled by Typo3 but by the webserver settings. I added an answer with .htaccess config which should fix the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the expiration dates by adding the following config to your `.htaccess` (you might have to add/remove some config to match your exact criteria but the pattern should be clear):

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
```

This does set the expire times to 1 week for the given file mimetypes. As said you maybe have to adjust which file mimetypes are controlled to get rid of all your warnings.